# String equality in bash strings are equal when actually they are not

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
STR1="David20"
STR2="fbhfthtrh"

if [ "$STR1"="$STR2" ]; then

        echo "Both the strings are equal"
else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
fi
```

Comment: You need a space both sides of the equal sign: `"$STR1" = "$STR2"`

Comment: in bash use `[[  ]]`, also use this site to validate your scripts. https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `"$STR1"="$STR2"` is equivalent to `"$STR1=$STR2"`. You need to delimit with space.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @ Kamil Maciorowski

Answer (score 5):

`[` is a normal command (although a builtin) and the closing `]` is just an argument to it. So is `"$STR1"="$STR2"` after the variables are expanded and quotes removed. The point is `"$STR1"="$STR2"` becomes *one* argument, and where there is just one argument before `]` and it's a non-empty string, the result is true (exit status `0`).

You want

```
[ "$STR1" = "$STR2" ]
```

Now there are *three* arguments before `]` and the middle one (`=`) tells the command you want to compare strings.

Comment: Even with `[[` (which _isn't_ a normal command), `[[ $a=$b ]] && echo yes` always prints `yes`, for the same reason.